# Storm supervisors,workers allocation of Memory

Tags: apache-storm

I'm having storm cluster with 3 Nodes: supervisors-2, Nimbus-1. 3 Nodes has 30 Gb of Ram and 4 cpu-cores. In configs I had configured:

```
supervisor.slots.ports : 8 (6700-6708)
supervisor.childopts  :-Xmx4096m _JAAS_PLACEHOLDER 
ui.childopts :-Xmx1024m _JAAS_PLACEHOLDER
nimbus.childopts :-Xmx6144m _JAAS_PLACEHOLDER
```

I want to know:

1. How this slots acts on supervisor nodes? In my opinion for each supervisor node we are assigning 8 ports . That means how many workers I will get for the cluster?
2. For supervisor childopts it is configured that 4 Gb of Ram. what is this means? similarly nimbus childopts?
3. suppose if I am running a topology with 3 workers by this configuration what is the Ram used and CPU cores used? 
   How can I calculate Ram utilisation and CPU for particular Topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 8 ports -> 8 workers. Each worker is assigned one of the ports.
2. supervisor.childopts are passed to the supervisor process. Same goes for nimbus.childopts.
3. workers may be running on different machines. Each worker is a separate process. You can note the memory/cpu of each process.

Comment: That means 8 ports 8 workers , 2 nodes 16 workers! am i correct...can i get small example to understand better... I want to understand more about Ram and Cpu utilisation. When we take 3 workers. How much ram is utilised ? similarly cpu?

Comment: @Anji RAM utilization and CPU utilization is purely based on your business logic. Which means it depends upon how much load/work are you giving to the workers. For example, If a worker has business logic to store 1000000 string object you may require X GB of heap memory, When you increased to store 2000000 object then use must increase your heap to Y GB (where Y > X).

Comment: @Anji In simple, I can say comment all your business logic in all your worker and analyze through JVisualVM/Jconsole so that you can conclude how much RAM and CPU utilization is required for a worker to survive. Then un-comment your business logic and analyze through JVisualVM/Jconsole and compare the deviation. So that you can get a clear cut idea about RAM and CPU usage.

Comment: @Anji -  what is the purpose of supervisor.childopts

Answer (score 1):

To be able to set requested resources(RAM & CPU) by each component(bolt/spout) and available resources on each node, you can use [this scheduler](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html). this way you can specify available RAM & CPU on each node and determine how much of each resource should be allocated to each worker process.

### Requested Resources by Components

**setMemoryLoad(Number onHeap)**:

```
builder.setBolt("exclaim1", new ExclamationBolt(), 3)
        .shuffleGrouping("word").setMemoryLoad(512.0);
```

**setCPULoad(Double amount)**:

```
builder.setBolt("exclaim2", new HeavyBolt(), 1)
            .shuffleGrouping("exclaim1").setCPULoad(450.0);
```

### Available Resources in worker nodes

add this parameters to *storm.yaml*

```
supervisor.memory.capacity.mb: [amount<Double>]

supervisor.cpu.capacity: [amount<Double>]
```

for more details on how Scheduling process is done, you can read [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjqg6GyzKXRAhUDIMAKHdpaDQkQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fassured-cloud-computing.illinois.edu%2Ffiles%2F2014%2F03%2FR-Storm-Resource-Aware-Scheduling-in-Storm.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHmsZJmRJx6QzQZfcuazMghhGfoyw&sig2=BUBVn-ncVGhozcM0Z4amKQ&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d24)